# Newcommand \Log

Tags: macros, amsart

I would like to define a `\Log` command which does essentially the same as `\log`, but has a capital first letter (I want to use both of them). I am using `amsart` (I think this does not matter).

Comment: The kernel defines `\def\log{\mathop{\operator@font log}\nolimits}`, so i assume `\def\Log{\mathop{\operator@font Log}\nolimits}` can work.

Comment: Thanks. Both worked fine for me. Can you shortly explain why the second one is better?

Comment: Ah very nice. I will have a closer look at this. Thanks!

Comment: @Johannes_B why not the standard `\DeclaeMathOperator\Log{Log}`? `amsart` is loading `amsmath`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard method of making `\log` like macros (requires `amsmath`, which `amsart` loads automatically) is to use

```
\DeclareMathOperator\Log{Log}
```

Addendum: If you instead use `\DeclareMathOperator*` then the created macro will behave like `\lim`, that is `_n` goes under the name in a displayed context

Comment: Isn't this a clear duplicate?

Comment: @egreg probably, it was faster to write an answer than to find the duplicate

Comment: I added an entry in the [“Often referenced questions”](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions/2427#2427) meta thread. However, searching for `declaremathoperators is:answer score:10` seems fast enough, doesn't it? http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=declaremathoperator+is%3Aanswer+score%3A10

Comment: @egreg bookmarked

Comment: @egreg Personally, i find this answer better in terms of style. There is no mention of `amsmath` at all. Often, the questions we use for closing as dupe are of that kind of (missing) *quality* and many of them would need a bit of extra explanation.

Comment: @Johannes_B You can always improve an answer, like I did. That answer was given in the first days of the site, when the standards were not yet established.

Comment: @egreg Yeah, i know. The earl days. Thans for updating the answer, now i could finally get it an upvote. :-)